# what does it mean when there is import error?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am using a code sample that suppose to be working, but I keep get an error with those 3 import statement.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.MultipartUploadCallable;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.PutObjectCallable;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.TransferStateUpdatingCallable;
```

the error message says : The import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.MultipartUploadCallable cannot be resolved

why is that happening and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Have you added necessary JAR files to a classpath?

Comment: You need to place library on classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Please add jars that contain this classes. This will always solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This means that implementations of referenced classes cannot be found in classpath. Since you are using `amazonaws` you should add appropriate library to your project's dependencies.